# I Get a Black Screen when Trying to Boot from a USB

Tags: windows-7, boot, usb, bootable-media

A while ago, I had a virus corrupt my OS. I found a Windows 7 boot USB, and tried booting from it. The logo appears, and then I get a black screen, the cursor doesn't blink if that makes a difference. The Computer and USB are both Windows 7 64 bit. I can't do anything on the computer, as the OS is corrupt. Why won't it boot?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's difficult to answer without more information.  Is your computer custom-built, or is it from a major Manufacturer?  If so, what model is it, or what model is your custom-built motherboard?  It could be that your computer doesn't support booting to USB, it could be the USB stick you have is corrupted.

Can you boot from that USB stick in a different computer?  Can you normally boot from USB devices in your computer?

Comment: I don't think that it can boot from USB. Do I just have to copy to a CD, or do I have to do something special?

Comment: Well, if you have a computer from a major manufacturer, you should be able to use the built-in recovery partition to reinstall windows.  Is your computer a major brand, or is it a custom build?

Comment: It's a Dell Optiplex

Comment: As long as you haven't replaced your original hard drive or changed your partitions, you can use Dell's recovery partition to reinstall windows.  Right after you turn the computer on, press Control AND F11 at the same time several times.  The PC should boot into the recovery manager instead of booting into windows.  From there, you will be able to launch the system recovery and reset the system to factory defaults. For more specific instructions, refer to [http://www.dell.com/support/troubleshooting/us/en/19/KCS/KcsArticles/ArticleView?docid=266327]